# Visual Studio doesn't recognize GCC linker Errors in Makefile Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

We have a cross compiled visual studio Makefile project. We have already had to introduce a [solution similar to this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/370890/GCCFilter-A-script-for-compiling-with-GCC-in-Visua) to get it to recognize compiler errors. Ie. We have introduced a Perl script to parse the output from GCC and convert it into a form that Visual studio will understand. If we declare:

```
int succ = thisRandomFunction(userPointer, 1, 1);
```

with no definition for `thisRandomFunction` then we will get the linker error:

```
1>  ./program.a(taskqueue.o): In function `TaskQueueAdd': 1> 
D:\Git\program\taskqueue.c(94,1) : undefined reference to `thisRandomFunction' 1>  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 1>  make: *** [program.exe] Error 1
```

But visual studio doesn't actually recognize this as an error. A Visual Studio C++ console program with the same problem has the linker error:

```
1>  TestUndefinedReference.cpp
1>TestUndefinedReference.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl something(int)" (?something@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>D:\Projects\New folder\TestUndefinedReference\Debug\TestUndefinedReference.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

By using this converter:

```
sub parseLinkerError
{
    my $str = $_[0];
    my $find = "undefined reference to";
    my $replace = "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol";
    $str =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
    return $str
}
```

We can convert this:

```
1>  d:\Git\program/taskqueue.c:94: undefined reference to `thisRandomFunction'
```

into this

```
1>  D:/Git/eV+/program/taskqueue.c(94,1) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `thisRandomFunction'
```

But this isnt enough to trick the visual studio linker error interpreter. **What are the minimum requirements for it to see a linker error?** Are there any solutions that can work without directly parsing the text?

Comment: All in all that's a good question after reading your link to code project (please excuse my former quirks).  You should make this more prominent, explain in a short summary, to get a concise answer for your question. I haven't one myself, sorry.

Comment: Did you try adding a slash conversion, from '/' to '\'?  $str =~ s/\//\\/;

Comment: @JimBlack Yep, we do convert the "\". Adjusting the question

Comment: Now the “We can convert this” part does not correspond to the Perl code you give above. Not a big deal, just a little WTF. Don’t know the answer, either.

Comment: @Ben Try changing the `print` in your Perl script to `print STDERR`. Maybe VS doesn't see the error because you're printing to STDOUT.

Comment: @Mithaldu I dont think this will help, we print to STDOUT for the rest of the compiler errors and VS detects all compiler errors and warnings.

Comment: In that case the question has little to do with Perl, and more with the exact formatting of the error.

Comment: @Mithaldu The currently implemented solution is to do with perl, it is part of the question. The answer in my mind is "Here is the minimal format for a linker error to be recognized in VS, and here is the parsing perl script."

Comment: The latter is just asking "Please give me the codes." and that on a particularly trivial point to boot. Additionally, frankly, you could try to put in a little more effort. You've done a single change in the strings in question, VS has bailed and then you immediately gave up instead of actually trying further changes.

Comment: SO submitted my comment because i hit enter while trying to insert a newline. So here's the rest of my comment as a second one: `1>  D:/Git/eV+/program/taskqueue.c(94,1) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `thisRandomFunction'` is wildly different from `1>TestUndefinedReference.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl something(int)" (?something@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main` So your first step should be to actually produce a conversion that's at least similar.

Comment: @Mithaldu You cant have vertical space in comments, you can use `shift-enter` for editing which might make it easier for you. As for the example given, this was simply to show the difference between a VS Linker Error and a GCC Linker Error. The VS one is a simple example, the GCC one is from the actual project that i am trying to compile. The Later example where i have actually tried to convert are both from the same project.

Comment: @Mithaldu As for the attempts, we have tried several more conversions. That is why the crux of the question is **What are the minimum requirements for it to see a linker error?** Which is simple, defined and well within this websites scope. I can hope for a code example in the answer, but i didnt post it in the question because i know it is off topic. Thank you for your advice though.

Comment: @Palec Yep, that is the Perl part to handle the linker changes. We have another part to convert `function:101:9` to the `function(101, 9)` that VS expects (As well as some other slight changes). Very similar to the article that i provided in the link at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx)...

The format of the output should be:

```
{filename (line# [, column#]) | toolname} : 
[any text] {error | warning} code####: localizable string
```

Where:

- {a | b} is a choice of either a or b.
- [ccc] is an optional string or parameter.

For example:

```
C:\sourcefile.cpp(134) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'somelib.lib'
```

---

Your sample fails because it's missing a required colon

```
D:/Git/eV+/program/taskqueue.c(94,1) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `thisRandomFunction'
                                    ^
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't find this documentation when i was constructing the perl script. This has highlighted several problems with the script.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like adding this line is enough to do it:

```
taskqueue.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "thisRandomFunction" referenced in function TaskQueueAdd
```

As far as i can tell the error will be detected via the following keys:

```
[*].obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "[*]" referenced in function [*]
```

Where the `[*]` can be anything or nothing (it doesn't even need to be the actual function).

So the following script is enough to parse it:

```
my $previousUsedInFunction = "";

sub parseLinkerError
{
    my $str = $_[0];
    my $find = "undefined reference to";

    #check that our string contains the undefined reference to substring. 
    if (index($str, $find) != -1) {

        #Use regular expressions to get the important filename. 
        my $filename = "";
        if ($str =~ /\\([a-zA-Z0-9_.]*)\(/) {
            $filename = $1;
            #replace whatever filename we find with the .obj equivelent. 
            $filename =~ s/\.cpp$/\.obj/g;
            $filename =~ s/\.h$/\.obj/g;
            $filename =~ s/\.c$/\.obj/g;
        }

        #Use regular expressions to find the function name. 
        my $function = "";
        if ($str =~ /\`([a-zA-Z0-9_.()]*)\'/) {
            $function = $1;
        }

        #create the final string similar to what visual studio expects. 
        my $finalStr = " " . $filename . ' : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "' . $function . '" referenced in function ' . $previousUsedInFunction . "\n";

        return $finalStr;

    }
    return $str;
}
```

Where the string `$previousUsedInFunction` is generated in the main parsing loop using the following if statement (to detect if we had an in function reference) :

```
elsif (/\.o\): In function \`([a-zA-Z0-9_.():]*)\'/) {
    print ("$_");
    $previousUsedInFunction = $1;       
}
```