# Possible linker errors to parse for visual studio compiling with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-studio-2012, linker

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572091/visual-studio-doesnt-recognize-gcc-linker-errors-in-makefile-project), Visual Studio cannot parse and display errors from GCC in `c` or `c++`. I have found at least one instance where linker errors are not found by the error parsing script in the answer.

As far as i have found there are two major linker errors that occur.

### Unresolved external symbol

Caused by the following examples (amoung others):

```
extern int i; // No definition of i
void nodef(); // No definition of a function

class A {
   static int b; // No external definition (int A::b) of b (c++ only)
}
```

### No Such file or directory

If an object file (`.o`) is removed before the linker runs, you have an error occur. This is usually caused by a `git-cleanup` followed by a regular build (instead of rebuild), currently this error case is not covered by the linked questions answer. But this is an easy fix.

**Are there any other linker errors (other than unresolved external and no such file) in c/c++ that I need to be aware of for complete coverage of this error parsing script?**

Comment: You need to be aware of every possible error, don't you?

Comment: GCC doesn't seem to have a list of linker errors, but here's MSVC's list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzaatbst.aspx

Comment: @immibis The GNU linker is not part of GCC itself.

Comment: I think creating this script would be on the level of Wine in reverse, translating POSIX to Windows. It would probably be much easier in the long run to use the VS linker with GCC. [Example from MinGW page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one other error is `Multiple definition of` when something is defined multiple times.