# Visual studio equivalent error for "array index out of bounds"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2015

We have a GCC makefile project building from visual studio. I have previously posted about problems with [visual studio not interpreting GCC errors and warnings here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572091/visual-studio-doesnt-recognize-gcc-linker-errors-in-makefile-project).

We want to add the `-Werror` flag to GCC to make sure no warnings are introduced to our code. Unfortunately there are still some outstanding warnings, and so our build fails. One example is the following:

In GCC we get the following:

> error: array subscript is above array bounds

Because of this, when built in Visual studio at the end we get this:

```
1>  stl_vector.h: In constructor 'RobotController()':
1>  stl_vector.h(1043,1) : error: array subscript is above array bounds
1>  stl_vector.h: In constructor 'RobotController()':
...   
1>  make[1]: *** [exe/obj/controller.o] Error 1
1>  make: *** [compilation] Error 2
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Which indicates to all post build events that the build succeeded.

**Is there an equivalent Visual studio warning or error for "array index out of bound" that I can convert this to?**

The aim is to report an error that makes sense to the user.
*Note: the warning itself is not a problem here and will be fixed separate, we simply want to report errors of this type correctly and in a way visual studio understands.*

Comment: Could you post an [mcve]?

Comment: The posted code is correct by the way, and should not produce that warning by itself. I'd guess there's interference from something else producing the warning.  I know this because _this code contains no array subscripts_.

Comment: Could you post RobotController() constructor?

Comment: Did you check line 1043?

Comment: 1043 is the line that generates the error. I think that you should check it. If it is a widely used library, it does not mean that is error free. Since the size of the structure is known at compile time, it might try some sort of optimization trick.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think i confused you about what was important about this question. I have edited it, please don't worry about the warning itself, i am more interested in the visual studio equivalent. I thought the original question outlined that pretty well, but hopefully this is better.

Comment: @ZDF The question is not really about solving this warning. I have re-edited.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Are you looking for #error PP directive?

Comment: @ZDF, no read the question linked, we have a perl script that parses the GCC output and converts it to a version interpreted well by VS, I need the VS equivalent error to "array index out of bound"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182089.aspx

> warning C6386: buffer overrun: accessing `<buffer name>`, the writable size is `<size1>` bytes, but `<size2>` bytes may be written: Lines: x, y

Note that this can only be caught by enabling the static code analysis tools.